# vuetify breakpoint when printing from mobile

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

when printing a vue component made with help of vuetify on mobile it only shows the component as if it was in mobile , not a4 size , how can I force it to use a4 size when printing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [Mobile Breakpoint](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#mobile-breakpoints), then, resize the component with computed props.

See: [Breakpoint Service](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service).